# How to resize views for multiple iOS screen sizes using auto layout programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

I am using an extension for my auto-layout as such:

```
extension UIView{

func anchorSize(to view: UIView){
    widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    
    heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor).isActive = true
}

func anchor(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, leading: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, trailing: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, padding: UIEdgeInsets = .zero, size: CGSize = .zero){
    
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    if let top = top{
        topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: padding.top).isActive = true
    }
    
    if let leading = leading{
        leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leading, constant: padding.left).isActive = true
    }
    
    if let trailing = trailing{
        trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailing, constant: padding.right).isActive = true
    }
    
    if let bottom = bottom{
        bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: padding.bottom).isActive = true
    }
    
    
    if size.width != 0 {
        widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.width).isActive = true
    }
    
    if size.height != 0 {
        heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.height).isActive = true
    }

}
}
```

However, I've come across an issue in which when displaying my views on different screen sizes the views become squished or simply don't fit.  How would I go about resizing the views through auto-layout to fit multiple screen sizes?  This is also the code for when I apply the constraints to something like a label:

```
    logo.anchor(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, leading: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0))
    logo.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    
    
    subLogo.anchor(top: logo.bottomAnchor, leading: logo.leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: logo.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0))
    subLogo.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
```

The iPhone 11 is the correct way of how I would auto layout. I really want to universally resize all my views for other devices.

[Here are the screenshots of the example devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTDJT.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, i think you add the code at viewdidload(), move that code to view didLayoutSubview(). as it will get updated frame after layout update

Comment: GAVIN - the code you've shown *appears* to be positioning `logo` 660 points above the top of the safe area (that is, way off the top of the screen). So, forget about your constraints for a moment... Edit your question and explain (preferably with an image or two) what you are trying to do.

Comment: @DonMag Hi I updated the post with the photos and fixed the padding.  Thank you.

Comment: @GAVINALFARO - There are people who make a very good living doing Interface Design. It's not a simple as laying out elements so they look good on one screen size / resolution, and expecting it to "magically" look good on all of them. You really need to think about how you *want* it to look on the different devices first and ***then*** figure out what constraints you need, which elements need to be "grouped" in subviews and/or stack views, where you want spacing to grow / shrink, etc.

Comment: @GAVINALFARO - as an example, here are three variations of your screen: https://imgur.com/a/lMDWXph ... none is probably exactly what you want, but it will hopefully help you understand that you need to put plenty of thought into how you want your UI to look across different devices.

Answer (score -1):

If you can show what you are actually talking about from screenshots, would help me a lot to see what’s going on.
By the way you are missing `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` in `func anchorSize()`. Also what are you trying to achieve by having a negative padding amount for top?

Comment: This should be a comment, as it does not answer the question.

Comment: I do not have commenting privileges yet.